# How to allow an instance to delete old snapshots of an attached volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a cloudformation template that would create a EC2 instance, mount a 2GB volume and do periodic snapshots, while also deleting the ones that are say a week or more old.

While I could get and integrate the access and secret keys, it seems that a signing certificate is required to delete snapshots. I could not find a way to create a new certificate with cloudformation, so it seems like I should create a new user and certificate manually and put that to the template parameters? In this case, is it correct that the user would be able to delete all the snapshots, including the ones that are not from that instance?

Is there a way to restrict snapshot deleting to only the ones with matching description? Or what's the proper way to handle deleting old snapshots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation is to create an IAM role (not IAM user) with CloudFormation and assign this role to the instance (again using CloudFormation).  The role should be allowed to delete snapshots as appropriate.

One of the easiest ways to delete the snapshot using the IAM role on the instance is to use the boto Python AWS library.  Boto automatically finds and uses the correct credentials if you run it on the instance with the assigned IAM role.

Here is a simple boto script I just used to delete snapshot `snap-51930522` in `us-east-1`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto.ec2
boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1').delete_snapshot('snap-51930522')
```

Alternatively, you might have an external server run the snapshot cleanup instead of running it on the instances themselves.  In addition to simplifying credential management and cron job distribution, it also lets you clean up after stopped or terminated instances.

Comment: Would you mind to explain this `The role should be allowed to delete snapshots as appropriate.`, I can only allow it to delete all the snapshots in the account, right?

Comment: @Fluffy: All I mean is that once you figure out what permissions should be allowed, you can assign them to this role.  No, you can't give yourself permission to delete other people's things.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to allow the role only delete snapshots of one specific volume

Comment: e.g. if that instance gets compromised, attacker can't delete all the snapshots

Comment: @Fluffy: At this time, the Amazon EC2 service does not currently support the use of ARNs (Amazon Resource Names) to restrict controlling access to specific resources with a given function like DeleteSnapshot.  However, they are aware that folks would like to have finer tuned control and have stated publicly that they are looking at things like this.